# Error Running UWP Project (UniversalWindows)

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, cross-platform, xlabs

I am making a crossplatform xamirin forms application that should run on android and pc windows.

During compiling the UWP version I get the exceptions:

> Can not resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.dll

and

> Type universe can not resolve assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8,
>   Version = 1.5.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null

I read about these exceptions on the internet and from what I could see, it is related to the Xlabs plugin being used in the application. Is this information correct?

If yes, would I have some way to fix it without removing the Xlabs plugin, why am I using it on multiple forms to be able to checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issues because of Nuget package was not up to date in my every project. I tried to fix this issues using below step.

- Close the Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio.
- Delete the Nuget package folder from root directory.
- Delete the all bin, obj and debug folder from every project folder.
- Right click on every project of Package folder and try to update.
- Clean the all solution and Rebuild all.